# Getting a Token Comma Expected error when Trying to pull in a Json file

Tags: powerquery

I'm trying to load a JSON file into Excel, but I'm having trouble with the query in the advanced editor.

I get a "Token comma expected" Error. It highlights the "in". When I put a comma after (source), then I get a "Token literal expected" error. Also highlighting the in.

```
let
    Source=Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\CDO Data\us-east-2.json"),#"Converted to Table"=Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a a close-paren in the definition of `Source`. You call two functions, `Json.Document` and `File.Contents`, but you only have one close-paren before the definition of `#"Converted to Table"`. Here it is formatted and with the close-paren:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\CDO Data\us-east-2.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```